# STS Dashboard non UTF-8 characters

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I have downloaded Spring Tool Suite 3.8.3. But the Dashboard is showing non UTF-8 characters.

[image]

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in JavaFX webkit font rendering. We changed the font settings on that dashboard page to make it work again. The fix will be released with STS 3.8.4 (arriving soon). In the meantime, you can switch to the old dashboard via the preferences.

More details here: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4422

Comment: Hi @Martin Lippert, Thanks for the update. Already switched to the older version of the dashboard and will wait for the 3.8.4 update.